# Using custom fonts in email like Jukely

Tags: email, fonts, font-face

I've searching some answer, like [this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email) but nothing works.
How can I insert custom fonts (for me is Proxima Nova that I use until with typekit) in a newsletter?
Like as Jukely use in their email hat works on any email client!
Please someone can help me?

Thanks, Enri

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Typekit requires Javascript to work, which is a big no-no in emails. You have two options:

1. You can download and host the font on your own domain, and use `@import` to link to it (detailed instructions are the same as option 2):

   `@import url('https://www.mydomain.com/fonts/proxima-nova.css');`
2. You can find a somewhat similar font in the [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) library (such as '[Montserrat](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Montserrat)'), and use CSS `@import`, as described in the Campaign Monitor link. You can use it like this:

   `<style>
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
   h4 {
   font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
   color: #444444;
   font-size: 24px;
   }
   </style>`

You will still see your back-up font (`Arial, sans-serif` in the example) in a lot of email clients, so make sure you're prepared for that, but you should be looking pretty good in iOS Mail, Outlook, Apple Mail, Android (default client) and Thunderbird.

@font-face support is much worse in emails, with only the Apple Mail app seeming to support it, FYI.

Sources:

http://css-tricks.com/custom-fonts-in-emails/

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email